# Point Inside Circle Collision Response: How do you keep the Point inside of the circle?

Tags: java, collision-detection, geometry, point

[image: Diagram of the meaning of this question.]

I have given a diagram of my current small problem that I need help with. My main purpose is to keep the point from going **outside** the circle. Nothing else.

The center of the circle is positioned at (x, y).

I only solved a little bit of the problem, and that is the collision detection part of my problem, as given below:

```
public void bound(Point p, Circle c){
    double distance = Math.hypot(p.x - c.x, p.y - c.y);
    if (distance >= c.radius){
        //Clueless from here on out.
    }
}
```

The part where I left a comment is the spot I couldn't figure anything out. I did tried to set the point's `velocityX` and `velocityY` to 0, but I realized the point will just stay put whenever it touches the circle.

So, I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, it's a mechanics question (and is therefore off-topic).  Assuming an elastic collision, the reflection is [specular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_reflection).  You just need to calculate the tangent to the circle at the point of collision.

Comment: How do you get the tangent to the circle at the point of collision? I tried `Math.atan2()`, but people say that's an arc tangent. Should I be using `Math.tan()` instead?

Comment: It's not very tricky, but it's hard to explain without a diagram.  I suggest you draw out a diagram, and figure out the geometry.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Okay, I tried drawing the diagram on a piece of paper. You cannot obtain a tangent line if (A): Distance between the point and the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle, and (B): You only have 2 points at a time. In Java, how do you precisely set a point A outside of the circle that you can somehow connect to the point of collision so that it creates a tangent line? Please enlighten me.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Rephrasing: Once the point hits the circle, I obtain a point of collision X(a,b), which is also on the tangent of the circle. What is the next step in Java? As in, what else should I do next that will help me in keeping the point's (x,y) constant, and won't make the point be stuck at the point of collision? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know the current position and velocity of the object, then you can figure out the coordinates where it would intersect with the circle.  You can then obtain the tangent to the circle at that point, or more specifically the normal to the circle at that point.  Once you know that, you can calculate the angle to the normal that the point is moving at, and use that to calculate the angle that it will reflect at.  You can use the angle to determine the new velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

```
public void reflect(Hole h){
    //R = -2*(V dot N)*N + V
    //N is normalized.
    double nx = (this.position[0]+this.diameter/2) - (h.x+16);
    double ny = (this.position[1]+this.diameter/2) - (h.y+16);
    double nd = Math.hypot(nx, ny);
    if (nd == 0)
        nd = 1;
    nx /= nd;
    ny /= nd;
    double dotProduct = this.speed[0]*nx+this.speed[1]*ny;
    this.speed[0] += (float)(-2*dotProduct*nx);
    this.speed[1] += (float)(-2*dotProduct*ny);
}

public void reflectResponse() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        position[i] -= speed[i];
        speed[i] *= 0.992f;
    }
}
```

I tried Oli Charlesworth's method from the comments, but it made things more... "complicated" than I expected. Someone else mentioned I used a completely 100%, vector-based algorithm, since I'm relying a lot on vector-based movements.

**TIPS TO THOSE WHO DO READ THIS:**

1. If you're working on object movements and collisions with vectors, seek vector-based algorithms.
2. If you're working with angles (either degrees or radians), use Oli Charlesworth's method.